# Unable to fix the issue of List Index out of range in python and unable to get desired output by ploting points

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, trigonometry

This is the program to convert given sin signal into digital encoding using Pulse Code Modulation Method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
Amplitude=input("Enter the Amplitude: ")
Time=input("Enter the Time: ")
Frequency=1.0/Time
x=numpy.linspace(-Amplitude,Amplitude,num=Time*10)
series=Amplitude*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi/Frequency*x)
plt.plot(series)
plt.show()
Quantization=input("Enter the Quantization bit: ")
power=pow(2,Quantization-1)
Size=2*Amplitude/power
z=[]
for t in range(0,Time*10):
    if(series[t]>=0):
        p=0
        n=Size
        for k in range(0,power-1):
            if((series[t]>=p)and(series[t]<=n)):
                z.append(k+power)
                break
            p=n
            n=Size+n
    else:
        p=-1
        n=-Size
        for k in range(0,power-1):
            if((series[t]<=p)and(series[t]>=n)):
                z.append(power-k-1)
                break
            p=n
            n=n-Size
plt.plot(z)
plt.show()
print z
signal=[]
rem=0
for j in range(0,Time*10):
    i=1
    summ =0
    while 1:
        if(z[j]>0):
            rem=int(z[j])%2
            summ=summ+(i*rem)
            z[j]=z[j]/2
            i=i*10
        else:
            signal.append(summ)
            break
print signal
```

Following is the problem

```
[root@vijay ~]# python PCM.py
Enter the Amplitude: 20
Enter the Time: 10
Enter the Quantization bit: 3
[4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PCM.py", line 42, in <module>
    if(z[j]>0):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After commenting the last for loop, there is another problem in the output of the signal displayed. As if you run the following program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
Amplitude=input("Enter the Amplitude: ")
Time=input("Enter the Time: ")
Frequency=1.0/Time
x=numpy.linspace(-Amplitude,Amplitude,num=Time*10)
series=Amplitude*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi/Frequency*x)
plt.plot(series)
plt.show()
Quantization=input("Enter the Quantization bit: ")
power=pow(2,Quantization-1)
Size=2*Amplitude/power
z=[]
for t in range(0,Time*10):
    if(series[t]>=0):
        p=0
        n=Size
        for k in range(0,power-1):
            if((series[t]>=p)and(series[t]<=n)):
                z.append(k+power)
                break
            p=n
            n=Size+n
    else:
        p=-1
        n=-Size
        for k in range(0,power-1):
            if((series[t]<=p)and(series[t]>=n)):
                z.append(power-k-1)
                break
            p=n
            n=n-Size
plt.plot(z)
plt.show()
print z
```

We get 2 plots. 1 plot map is correct but the second one has a fault at Time = 60 (x-axis =60) as per the concept and programming desired value over there should be 3.0 but it is not.

Please help, I am new in python and unable to debug the issues. Thank You

Comment: the `z` list only has 98 elements (indexed from 0 to 97), while `j` runs from 0 to 99. So when `j` reaches 98... boom!

Comment: @Pynchia... ok....Please suggest the solution for it

Comment: do you expect advice on signal processing/numeric algorithms? I can do it , but I have to refresh my memory from Uni. :)

Comment: @Pynchia.... no no Thank you. Just tell me how to resolve that looping issue

Comment: my point is that the flaw seems to lie in how z is built, in the algorithm, not in an evident coding error (although the code can be improved / be neater)

Comment: @Pynchia.... Ooook   you are great (y) :) please suggest the alternative algorithm for it. the algorithm to built the z list.

Comment: Presumably, you're trying to do some sort of compressed PCM; that's _way_ too complicated for linear PCM.